# Поэтапные фильтры каталога на сайте недвижимости JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-сайт

требуется помощь с настройкой фильтров в для сайта недвижимости.
У меня есть каталог квартир, я сделал его списком `<ul>`.

Добавил некоторые классы для фильтрации: rooms-1 (по количеству комнат), floor-2 (по этажу) expluat-4 (по вводу в эксплуатацию)

value - это метраж.

Важное замечание, вся данные подтягиваются по API, то есть при формировании классов идет название, например rooms-(а тут параметр API).

В общем, задача такая, чтобы при выборе тех или иных параметров фильтровался список часть фильтров работает, но есть ряд вопросов.

1. Один из параметров - это цена, но какому атрибуту присвоить это значение - ума не приложу.
2. Есть параметр по номеру дома, но номера домов с русскими буквами, была бы латиница, я бы присвоил  еще один класс, но буквы русские, как поступить не знаю.
3. Как собрать все воедино, то есть, те фильтры, что работают - работают по отдельности, не сообща.

Код прикладываю, на всякий случай, прикладываю еще ссылку на codepen
https://codepen.io/andreypantyukhin/pen/rNQJJdZ?editors=1000

Очень прошу помочь, Вы моя последняя надежда)

```
<div class="ffilters-container">
  <div class="filters-container-sib-col flex">
            <div class="filter-container-sib-col-item calculator-item flex" id="rooms-id">
                <div class="filter-title">Количество комнат</div>
                <div class="filter-btns" id="myBtnContainer">
                    <button class="filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Все</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('rooms-1')">Студия</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('rooms-1')">1</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('rooms-2')">2</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('rooms-3')">3</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('rooms-4')">4</button>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="calculator-item filter-container-sib-col-item flex">
                    <div class="filter-title">Этаж</div>
                    <div class="first-payment-box flex">
                        <input type="number" id="floorNumberInputSib" value="2">
                        <input type="range" id="floorRangeInputSib" min="2" max="19" step="1" value="2" onchange="rangeInputFloorFunc ()">
                    </div>    
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filters-container-sib-col filter-container-sib-col-item flex">
            <div class="calculator-item flex">
                    <div class="filter-title">Отделка</div>
                    <select id="mortageSelect1Sib">
                        <option value="1">Без отделки</option>
                        <option value="2">С отделкой</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="calculator-item filter-container-sib-col-item flex">
                    <div class="filter-title">Площадь, м<sup>2</sup></div>
                    <div class="first-payment-box flex">
                        <input type="number" id="sqNumberInputSib" value="25">
                        <input type="range" id="sqRangeInputSib" min="25" max="120" step="1" value="25" onchange="rangeInputSqFunc ()">
                    </div>    
             </div>
            <div class="calculator-item filter-container-sib-col-item flex">
                    <div class="filter-title">Дом, №</div>
                    <select id="mortageSelect3Sib">
                        <option value="1">6А</option>
                        <option value="2">6Б</option>
                        <option value="2">6Г</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filters-container-sib-col filter-container-sib-col-item flex">
            <div class="calculator-item flex">
                    <div class="filter-title">Стоимость, &#8381;</div>
                    <div class="first-payment-box flex">
                        <input type="number" id="priceNumberInputSib" value="1000000">
                        <input type="range" id="priceRangeInputSib" min="1000000" max="20000000" step="50000" value="1000000" onchange="rangeInputPriceFunc ()">
                    </div>    
             </div>
            <div class="calculator-item filter-container-sib-col-item flex">
                    <div class="filter-title">Дата сдачи</div>
                    <select id="expluatationSelection">
                        <option value="0">Выберете срок сдачи</option>
                        <option value="1">3 квартал 2023</option>
                       <option value="2">4 квартал 2023</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="filter-container-sib-col-item flex" id="results-inner" ></div>
        </div>
</div>


    <div class="container plans-container flex">
        <div id="sibirPlans" class="sibir-plans">
      <ul class="sibir-plans-list list-reset flex">
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-2 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="25">Квартира 1</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-3 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="35">Квартира 2</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-4 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="45">Квартира 3</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-5 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="55">Квартира 4</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-6 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="65">Квартира 5</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-7 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="25">Квартира 6</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-8 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="35">Квартира 7</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-9 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="45">Квартира 8</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-10 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="55">Квартира 9</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-11 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="65">Квартира 10</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-12 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="25">Квартира 11</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-13 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="35">Квартира 12</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-14 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="45">Квартира 13</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-15 expluat-42023 flex" id="45"  value="55">Квартира 14</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-16 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="65">Квартира 15</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-17 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="25">Квартира 16</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-18 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="35">Квартира 17</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-19 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="45">Квартира 18</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-19 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="55">Квартира 19</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-18 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="65">Квартира 20</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-17 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="25">Квартира 21</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-16 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="35">Квартира 22</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-14 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="45">Квартира 23</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-13 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="55">Квартира 24</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-12 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="65">Квартира 25</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-11 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="25">Квартира 26</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-3 floor-10 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="35">Квартира 27</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-4 floor-9 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="45">Квартира 28</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-1 floor-7 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="55">Квартира 29</li>
        <li class="sibir-plans-list-item rooms-2 floor-4 expluat-32023 flex" id="45"  value="65">Квартира 30</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.ffilters-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.calculator-item {
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.filters-container-sib-col {
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 40px;
}
    /*Plans-list*/
    .plans-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-list {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        gap: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    
    .sibir-plans-list-item {
        height: 45vh;
        margin-bottom: 5vh;
        padding: 24px;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 200px;
        background: #F8F8F8;
        border-radius: 10px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-info-before {
        margin-bottom: 2vh;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: #000000;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-info-image {
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 2vh;
        height: 25vh;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-info-image img {
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-info-after {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-info-after-col-1 {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 33px;
        color: #000000; 
    }
    
    .sibir-plans-info-after-col-2 {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 33px;
        color: #565656;
    }

.show {
    display: flex!important;
}
    /*Ends Plans-list*/
```

```
var rangeInputFloor = document.getElementById('floorRangeInputSib');
var numberInputFloor = document.getElementById('floorNumberInputSib');
var rangeInputSq = document.getElementById('sqRangeInputSib');
var numberInputSq = document.getElementById('sqNumberInputSib');
var rangeInputPrice = document.getElementById('priceRangeInputSib');
var numberInputPrice = document.getElementById('priceNumberInputSib');
var valueFloor = parseInt(rangeInputFloor.value);
var valueSq = parseInt(rangeInputSq.value);
var valuePrice = parseInt(rangeInputPrice.value);
            
            function rangeInputFloorFunc () {
                    rangeInputFloor.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    const valueFloor = parseInt(rangeInputFloor.value);
                          if (!isNaN(valueFloor)) {
                             numberInputFloor.value = valueFloor;
                          }
                    });
                    
                    numberInputFloor.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    const valueFloor = parseInt(numberInputFloor.value);
                                if (!isNaN(valueFloor)) {
                                    if (valueFloor < parseInt(rangeInputFloor.min)) {
                                        rangeInputFloor.value = rangeInputFloor.min;
                                    } else if (valueFloor > parseInt(rangeInputFloor.max)) {
                                        rangeInputFloor.value = rangeInputFloor.max;
                                    } else {
                                        rangeInputFloor.value = valueFloor;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            };
            
            function rangeInputSqFunc () {
                    rangeInputSq.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    const valueSq = parseInt(rangeInputSq.value);
                          if (!isNaN(valueSq)) {
                             numberInputSq.value = valueSq;
                          }
                        //console.log("Test 4: " + valueSq);
                    });
                    
                    numberInputSq.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    const valueSq = parseInt(numberInputSq.value);
                            //console.log("Test 4: " + valueSq);
                                if (!isNaN(valueSq)) {
                                    if (valueSq < parseInt(rangeInputSq.min)) {
                                        rangeInputSq.value = rangeInputSq.min;
                                    } else if (valueSq > parseInt(rangeInputSq.max)) {
                                        rangeInputSq.value = rangeInputSq.max;
                                    } else {
                                        rangeInputSq.value = valueSq;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            
                function rangeInputPriceFunc () {
                    rangeInputPrice.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    const valuePrice = parseInt(rangeInputPrice.value);
                          if (!isNaN(valuePrice)) {
                             numberInputPrice.value = valuePrice;
                          }
                    });
                    
                    numberInputPrice.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    const valuePrice = parseInt(numberInputPrice.value);
                                if (!isNaN(valuePrice)) {
                                    if (valuePrice < parseInt(rangeInputPrice.min)) {
                                        rangeInputPrice.value = rangeInputPrice.min;
                                    } else if (valuePrice > parseInt(rangeInputPrice.max)) {
                                        rangeInputPrice.value = rangeInputPrice.max;
                                    } else {
                                        rangeInputPrice.value = valuePrice;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
function resultInnerFunc () {
        var rusultInnerBox = document.getElementById("results-inner");
        var elmsCount = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
        
        rusultInnerBox.innerHTML += `${elmsCount.length} подходящих предложений`;
        
        console.log(elmsCount.length);
    }
    
    filterSelection("all")
    function filterSelection(c) {
      var x, i;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("sibir-plans-list-item");
      if (c == "all") c = "";
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
      }
        
        var rusultInnerBox = document.getElementById("results-inner");
        
        rusultInnerBox.innerHTML = ' '; 
        resultInnerFunc ();
    }

    function w3AddClass(element, name) {
      var i, arr1, arr2;
      arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
      arr2 = name.split(" ");
      for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
      }
    }

    function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
      var i, arr1, arr2;
      arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
      arr2 = name.split(" ");
      for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
          arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
        }
      }
      element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

    

        function expluatationSelectionFunc () {
                    var expluat = document.getElementById("expluatationSelection");
                    var quarterOne = document.querySelectorAll('.sibir-plans-list .expluat-3-2023');
                    var quarterTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.sibir-plans-list .expluat-4-2023');
            
                    
                    
                    //console.log(quarterOne);
                    //console.log(quarterTwo);
            
                    expluat.addEventListener("change", function() {
                        
                    if (expluat.value == "1") {
                            quarterOne.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('blocked'));
                            quarterTwo.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('blocked'));
                            console.log(expluat.value);
                            console.log('3 квартал');
                            quarterTwo.forEach(n => {
                                if (n.classList.contains('blocked')) {
                                        console.log('item is blocked');
                                    } else {
                                        n.classList.remove('show');
                                        n.classList.add('blocked');
                                    }
                            }
                            );
                            quarterOne.forEach(n => {
                                if (n.classList.contains('blocked')) {
                                        console.log('item is blocked');
                                    } else {
                                        n.classList.add('show');
                                    }
                            }
                            );
                        } else if ((expluat.value == "2")) {
                            quarterOne.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('blocked'));
                            quarterTwo.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('blocked'));
                            console.log(expluat.value);
                            console.log('4 квартал');
                            quarterTwo.forEach(n => {
                                if (n.classList.contains('blocked')) {
                                        console.log('item is blocked');
                                    } else {
                                        n.classList.add('show');
                                    }
                            }
                            );
                            quarterOne.forEach(n => {
                                if (n.classList.contains('blocked')) {
                                        console.log('item is blocked');
                                    } else {
                                        n.classList.remove('show');
                                        n.classList.add('blocked');
                                    }
                            }
                            );
                            
                            quarterOne.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('show'));
                            quarterTwo.forEach(n => n.classList.add('show'));
                        }
                        var rusultInnerBox = document.getElementById("results-inner");
        
                        rusultInnerBox.innerHTML = ' '; 
                        resultInnerFunc ();
                    })
        }
    
        function floorRangeInputSibSelectionFunc () {
            var floors = document.getElementById("floorRangeInputSib");
            var hidElem = document.querySelectorAll('.sibir-plans-list-item');
            var flValue = floors.value;
            //console.log(flValue);
            
            floors.addEventListener("change", function() {
                var hidElem = document.querySelectorAll('.sibir-plans-list-item');
                console.log(hidElem);
                hidElem.forEach(a => {
                    console.log(a);
                if (a.classList.contains('blocked')) {
                    console.log('item is blocked');
                } else {
                    a.classList.remove('show');
                    a.classList.add('blocked');
                    var flValue = floors.value;
                    var curFloor = document.querySelectorAll('.floor-' + flValue);
                    curFloor.forEach(n => { 
                        n.classList.add('show');
                        n.classList.remove('blocked');
                    });
                    
                    //console.log(curFloor);    
                    //console.log(flValue);     
                    //console.log('Changed');   
                //
                }
                
                });
            
                var rusultInnerBox = document.getElementById("results-inner");
        
                        rusultInnerBox.innerHTML = ' '; 
                        resultInnerFunc ();
            })
        }
    
        function sqRangeInputSibSelectionFunc () {
            var sqMeters = document.getElementById("sqRangeInputSib");
            var sqMetersValue = sqMeters.value;
            console.log(sqMetersValue);
            
            
            sqMeters.addEventListener("change", function() {
                            
                var sqMetersValue = sqMeters.value;
                var hidMeters = document.querySelectorAll('.sibir-plans-list-item');
                hidMeters.forEach( n => {
                    var sqMetersValue = sqMeters.value;
                    if (n.value <= sqMetersValue) {
                        n.classList.add('show');
                        console.log(n.value);
                        console.log('Evrica!');
                        console.log(sqMetersValue);
                        console.log('Changed');
                    } else {
                        n.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                    
                    var rusultInnerBox = document.getElementById("results-inner");
        
                        rusultInnerBox.innerHTML = ' '; 
                        resultInnerFunc ();
                }
                
                );
                
            })
        }
    
        
    
    window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
                    console.log("page is fully loaded");
                    expluatationSelectionFunc ();
                    floorRangeInputSibSelectionFunc ();
                    sqRangeInputSibSelectionFunc ();
                    //resultInnerFunc ();
                });
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ответ от АПИ. Один из вариантов - не фильтровать по отрисованному DOM, а фильтровать по данным из АПИ и потом перерисовывать DOM под параметры фильтрации. Так же, вместо классов, разумнее использовать атрибут `data-*`, если уж вы хотите фильтровать по отрисованным элементам.